# Does this notation mean vector-concatenation?

Tags: neural-network, notation

When reading papers on neural networks, I occasionally stumble upon the following notation with a semicolon:

$$
\text{tanh}(\mathbf{W_c}[\mathbf{c}_t;\mathbf{h}_t])
$$

Unless otherwise noted, does this by default mean the following:

- vector $\mathbf{c}_t$ is **appended** to vector $\mathbf{h}_t$
- the resulting long vector is dot-producted with a Weight matrix $\mathbf{W}_t$
- Finally, the resulting vector is component-wise activated by a hyperbolic tangent function

The first bullet point is my main question.
Googling for "Vector concatenation notation" doesn't return answers that would resemble the image I've attached above. However, many papers seem to use it.

An example [of notation that I googled](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/298648/is-there-a-common-symbol-for-concatenating-two-finite-sequences)

Comment: Yes. Concatenation is the richest aggregation of mathematical objects. As opposed to, say, averaging.